# URL Conditional config in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My case is the following:

I have a file named mylogic.php. This file is called from two different URLs (/url1.php & /url2.php).

What I want to archive is to add some headers to the response *only* when mylogic.php is accessed from /url1.php.

Experts: Do you have a workaround to this issue?

THANKS in advance.

Comment: How is that file called from two different URLs exactly?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^url1.php mylogic.php
 RewriteRule ^url2.php mylogic.php
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want to do this in your htaccess, or is something like

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/url1.php' ) header('WeirdStuff: x');
```

sufficient

Comment: I would prefer to isolate this behavior in the htaccess file... but if there isn't any way to do it then this workaround will work

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] contains the name of the main PHP script (i.e. /url1.php or /url2.php). You can test the value of this variable and send the header when it matches the URL you want. Something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/url1.php') {
    doSomething();
}
```